# How to cancel the edit session?

Tags: arcobjects, arcmap, c#, editing, events

I want to prevent the user from starting an edit session under certain conditions.

How can I do that?

```
void m_editEvents_OnStartEditing()

        {
            // Code
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m_editor.StopEditing(false)` will stop the edit session.

- `false` to not save the changes
- `true` if you want to save the changes